# Is my structure of program readable?

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, winforms, dapper

Just looking for reviews to improve my coding and my structure of C#. It feels I probably have some unnecessary code that is not needed, been following some YouTube videos to accomplish some tasks.

Also, I am not sure if the actual structure is okay of my program. Would like to hear some opinions.

I am working on a project that sends a form to MySQL database. With a an extra bit of touch - Autofill most of the Text-boxes, from a button click and a given Sales Order Number found in SQL Server database.

If an Order Number is given then text boxes such as `Customer Name`, `Telephone`, `Email`, `Products` and `Pack size` is able to be auto-filled.

The `Products` is a combo-box value, so it'll be a list of ordered products and the user is able to selected a value.

This is the form:

[image]

**Code:**

**ComplaintModel.cs**

```
public class ComplaintModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int IsCustomerSelected { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerContactName { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
    public int IsProductSelected { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string PackSize { get; set; }
    public string BatchNumber { get; set; }
    public int IsBestBefore { get; set; }
    public DateTime BestBeforeDate { get; set; }
    public string QuantityInvolved { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

}
```

**ComplaintForm.cs**

```
public partial class Complaints_Form : Form
{
    BindingList<string> errors = new BindingList<string>();

    List<ComplaintModel> mjmOrderNumber = new List<ComplaintModel>();

    List<ComplaintModel> customerNames = new List<ComplaintModel>();

    List<ComplaintModel> productNames = new List<ComplaintModel>();

    public Complaints_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        loadCustomers();
        loadProducts();
    }

    private void loadCustomers()
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
        customerNames = db.LoadCustomers();
        customer_name.DataSource = customerNames;
        customer_name.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
        customer_name.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void loadProducts()
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
        productNames = db.LoadProducts();
        product.DataSource = productNames;
        product.DisplayMember = "Product";
        product.SelectedIndex = -1;

        pack_size.DataBindings.Add("Text", productNames, "PackSize", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }


    public void clearBindings()
    {
        customer_name.DataBindings.Clear();
        email.DataBindings.Clear();
        telephone.DataBindings.Clear();
        product.DataBindings.Clear();
        product.DataSource = null;
        product.Items.Clear();
        pack_size.DataBindings.Clear();
    }

    public void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearBindings();

        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();

        mjmOrderNumber = db.FindOrderNumber(orderNumber.Text);

        // Binding values from Sales Order Number here:
        customer_name.DataBindings.Add("Text", mjmOrderNumber, "CustomerName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        email.DataBindings.Add("Text", mjmOrderNumber, "Email", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        telephone.DataBindings.Add("Text", mjmOrderNumber, "Telephone", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        

        product.DataSource = mjmOrderNumber;
        product.DisplayMember = "Product";

        pack_size.DataBindings.Add("Text", mjmOrderNumber, "PackSize", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

    }

    private void FormValidation()
    {
        errors.Clear();

        ComplaintModel complaint = new ComplaintModel();
        complaint.Date = date.Value;
        complaint.IsCustomerSelected = customer_name.SelectedIndex;
        complaint.CustomerContactName = customer_contact.Text;
        complaint.Telephone = telephone.Text;
        complaint.Email = email.Text;
        complaint.CustomerReference = customer_ref.Text;
        complaint.IsProductSelected = product.SelectedIndex;
        complaint.PackSize = pack_size.Text;
        complaint.BatchNumber = batch.Text;
        complaint.IsBestBefore = bestBeforeQuestion.SelectedIndex;
        complaint.BestBeforeDate = best_before.Value;
        complaint.QuantityInvolved = quantity.Text;
        complaint.Details = details.Text;
        complaint.Comments = comments.Text;

        ComplaintsValidator validator = new ComplaintsValidator();

        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(complaint);

        if (results.IsValid == false)
        {
            foreach (ValidationFailure failure in results.Errors)
            {
                errors.Add($"- {failure.ErrorMessage}");
            }

            string message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors);
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Empty Fields", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            insertComplaintForm();
        }
    }

    private void insertComplaintForm()
    {
        var confirm = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure the details you have entered are Correct?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (confirm == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();

            db.InsertComplaint(UserDetails.userId, date.Value, orderNumber.Text, customer_name.Text, customer_contact.Text, telephone.Text, email.Text, customer_ref.Text, product.Text, pack_size.Text, batch.Text, best_before.Value, quantity.Text, details.Text, comments.Text);

            clearFields();
        }
    }

    void clearFields()
    {
        clearBindings();
        customer_name.SelectedIndex = -1;
        customer_name.ResetText();
        date.Value = DateTime.Today;
        customer_contact.Clear();
        telephone.Clear();
        email.Clear();
        customer_ref.Clear();
        
        batch.Clear();
        orderNumber.Clear();
        best_before.ResetText();
        quantity.Clear();
        details.Clear();
        comments.Clear();
        bestBeforeQuestion.SelectedIndex = -1;

        loadProducts();

        product.SelectedIndex = -1;
        product.ResetText();
        pack_size.Clear();
    }

    private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormValidation();
    }

    private void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearFields();
    }


}
```

**DataAccess.cs**

```
public class DataAccess
{

    public List<ComplaintModel> GetComplaint(string _OrderNumber)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    // Used in "ComplaintForm" to get list of Product and Customer Name from MJM Database.
    public List<ComplaintModel> FindOrderNumber(string orderNumber)
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.MJMconnString))
        {
            var output = conn.Query<ComplaintModel>($@"
                    SELECT 
                    TRIM(p.description) as Product,
                    p.searchRef1 as PackSize,
                    c.name AS CustomerName,
                    c.email as Email,
                    c.phone as Telephone
                    FROM SalesOrder so JOIN SalesOrderLine sol ON
                    so.id = sol.salesOrderID JOIN Customer c ON
                    so.customerID = c.id JOIN Product p ON
                    sol.productID = p.id WHERE so.number = '{orderNumber}'").ToList();
            return output;
        }
    }

    public List<ComplaintModel> LoadCustomers()
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.MJMconnString))
        {
            var output = conn.Query<ComplaintModel>($@"SELECT name AS CustomerName FROM Customer WHERE dormant = 0;").ToList();
            return output;
        }
    }

    public List<ComplaintModel> LoadProducts()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.MJMconnString))
        {
            var output = conn.Query<ComplaintModel>($@"SELECT CONCAT(description, ' - ', searchRef1) AS Product, searchRef1 AS PackSize FROM product WHERE dormant = 0").ToList();
            return output;
        }
    }

    // This is used to send Complaint details into MySQL database for table "CustomerComplaints"
    public void InsertComplaint(
        int userId,
        DateTime date,
        string orderNumber,
        string customerName,
        string customerContactName,
        string telephone,
        string email,
        string customerReference,
        string product,
        string packSize,
        string batchNumber,
        DateTime bestBeforeDate,
        string quantityInvolved,
        string details, 
        string comments)
    {
        using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
        {
            List<ComplaintModel> complaint = new List<ComplaintModel>();

            complaint.Add(new ComplaintModel {
                UserId = userId,
                Date = date,
                OrderNumber = orderNumber,
                CustomerName = customerName,
                CustomerContactName = customerContactName,
                Telephone = telephone,
                Email = email,
                CustomerReference = customerReference,
                Product = product,
                PackSize = packSize,
                BatchNumber = batchNumber,
                BestBeforeDate = bestBeforeDate,
                QuantityInvolved = quantityInvolved,
                Details = details,
                Comments = comments});

            conn.Execute(
                @"INSERT INTO CustomerComplaints
                (UserId, Date, OrderNumber, CustomerName, CustomerContactName, Telephone, Email, CustomerReference, Product, PackSize, BatchNumber,
                BestBeforeDate, QuantityInvolved, Details, Comments) 
                VALUES 
                (@UserId, @Date, @OrderNumber, @CustomerName, @CustomerContactName, @Telephone, @Email, @CustomerReference, @Product, @PackSize, @BatchNumber,
                @BestBeforeDate, @QuantityInvolved, @Details, @Comments)", complaint);
        }
    }


}
```

**ComplaintsValidator.cs**

```
public class ComplaintsValidator : AbstractValidator<ComplaintModel>
{
    public ComplaintsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.IsCustomerSelected)
            .Must(DropDownSelected).WithMessage("'Customer Name' must be valid");

        RuleFor(p => p.CustomerContactName)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(1, 100);

        RuleFor(p => p.Telephone)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(1, 40)
            .When(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Email));

        RuleFor(p => p.Email)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(1, 40)
            .When(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Telephone));

        RuleFor(p => p.CustomerReference)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .Length(0, 255);

        RuleFor(p => p.IsProductSelected)
            .Must(DropDownSelected).WithMessage("'Product Name' must be valid");

        RuleFor(p => p.PackSize)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(1, 40);

        RuleFor(p => p.BatchNumber)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(1, 40);

        RuleFor(p => p.IsBestBefore).Must(DropDownSelected).WithMessage("Does this product have a Best Before Date?");

        RuleFor(p => p.QuantityInvolved)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(1, 50);

        RuleFor(p => p.Details)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(10, 700);

        RuleFor(p => p.Comments)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .Length(0, 700);
    }

    protected bool DropDownSelected(int item)
    {
        if (item == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Resource**

This is the Youtube video I have used to make the queries etc..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et2khGnrIqc&t=2901s

Comment: Can you try putting this in your ORD number text box and doing the search? `' UNION ALL SELECT 'Google' as Product, 'SQL' as PackSize, 'Injection' AS CustomerName, 'Attacks,' as Email, 'Please' as Telephone -- ` and see what happens

Comment: including the `'` before `UNION`?

Comment: Yeah, all of it. I'm not that up to date on Dapper but I think you've got a problem.

Comment: @RobH This is the output: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`

Comment: Your app has an SQL Injection vulnerability and I apparently can't count how many columns there are in a select statement. https://www.troyhunt.com/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1/ - take a look at the "Anatomy of a SQL injection attack" section

Comment: @RobH Thank you - I'll have to add a parameter in my dapper function.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on your solution. Please note that some of the things I mention are my personal prefference.

ComplaintModel

- I preffer to name my `Id` field like `TableNameId`, so in your case I would change `Id` to `CustomerComplaintId` (please note that this is my personal prefference).
- `IsCustomerSelected` (and `IsProductSelected`) sounds like a `bool` flag to me, I see you put `SelectedIndex` in there. I would rename it to `CustomerId` and if you need the flag "is selected" then make a new property, make it a bool and change it's value accordingly.
- Regarding DB design are `BachNumber`, `QuantityInvolved` numerics? If so consider making them a proper type (int, decimal etc.), both in DB and model.

ComplaintForm

- Use PascalCase for class, method name and public properties. I would change `Complaints_Form` to `ComplaintsForm`, every method where you use camelCase, like `loadCustomers` -> `LoadCustomers`.
- I strictly specify modifier for private fields and prefix them with an underscore, in your case the top private fields would become `private List<ComplaintModel> _mjmOrderNumber = new List<ComplaintModel>();` (please note that this is my personal prefference).
- I'm not sure I understand how you reuse the `ComplaintModel` for Customers and Products, it seems they should be their own model (entity) which comes from Database.
- `clearBindings` method should be private, no need to expose it outside.
- You construct a new `ComplaintModel` inside FormValidation and indirectly in insertComplaintform. I would make a helper function which would populate and return your ComplaintModel which you can reuse in two locations mentioned above. You would need to change the DataAccess InsertComplaint method to accept a ComplaintModel instead of multitude of parameters.
- In the end of FormValidation method you execute the insertComplaintForm method, I would change the FormValidation method to return a bool `isFormValid` and execute the insertComplaintForm in saveBtn_Click event after checking if form is valid. Try and keep methods responsible for a single task.
- This one is food-for-thought and I'd actually like some feedback from others about this - after making numerous "ClearForm", "ClearFields" "EmptyInput" methods I later started reusing a function which would traverse all controls on the form and clear them - if TextBox then `Clear()` if ComboBox then `SelectedIndex = -1`. This way I never forgot to clear a field I added long time after I implemented the original functionality.

DataAccess

- I see now what you did with the `ComplaintModel`, you packed it with all database properties you need later on and simply fill the properties you need for lets say a ComboBox datasource. While this works it makes the `ComplaintModel` unneccesary complicated. I would return Customer(s) object from LoadCustomers, Product(s) object from LoadProducts and use those for control binding.
- As mentioned above I would change InsertComplaint to accept `ComplaintModel` object which would be constructed from a helper method in the Form itself.

ComplaintsValidator

- You can set CascadeMode globally or per Validator, no need to specify it for every Rule. Like this `CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop`;